# C++ Class Enumeration Member variable

Tags: c++, class, enumeration, member-functions

I have a class with an enumerated type GameStates.  In the (public) constructor I initialise GameStates like this:

```
GameStates enumGameState = Ready;
```

Then in a public method run() i have a switch like this:

```
switch(enumGameState)
        {
        case Ready:
            if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
            {
                enumGameState = Firing;
                cout << "\nGame State moved to Firing";
            }   // End if
            break;
        case Firing:
            if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
            {
                enumGameState = Contact;
                cout << "\nGame State moved to Contact";
            }   // End if
            break;
        case Contact:
            if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
            {
                enumGameState = Over;
                cout << "\nGame State moved to Over";
            }   // End if
            break;
        case Over:
            break;
        };  // End of GameState switch
```

Whilst the code does not error, none of the states are met. How should i be accessing the value of enumGameState?

EDIT: All class code.

```
class Game
{
private:
    Block* arrBlocks[10][10];   
    //IMesh* objBlockMesh;
    IMesh* objGunMesh;
    IMesh* objDummyMesh;
    Gun* objGun;
    int Game::intSpeed;
    I3DEngine* theGameEngine;
    float fltSkyboxXCo;
    float fltSkyboxYCo;
    float fltSkyboxZCo;
    float fltFloorXCo;
    float fltFloorYCo;
    float fltFloorZCo;

    enum GameStates{Ready,Firing, Contact, Over};
    GameStates enumGameState;

public: 

    Game(I3DEngine* the3dengine)
    {
        Game::theGameEngine = the3dengine;
        theGameEngine->StartWindowed();

        // Add default folder for meshes and other media
        theGameEngine->AddMediaFolder( "C:\\TL-Engine\\Media\\AssigmentTwo\\Media" );

        //intSpeed = 1;

        Game::DrawBasicScene(theGameEngine);
        Game::DrawBlocks();
        Game::CreateAGun();
        Bullet::Bullet(theGameEngine);
        Game::enumGameState = Ready;
    }   // End of Constructor


private:    


    void DrawBlocks()
    {
        float fltBlockOffSet = 12.0f;
        float fltLeftMost = -54.0f;
        float fltBlockZCo = 120.0f;
        float fltBlockYCo = 5.0f;
        float fltCurrentXCo;
        float fltCurrentYCo = 5.0f;
        float fltCurrentZCo = 120.0f;
        // Stick 10 blocks in an array
        // Display them

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1) // Once i have created the first row all the other blocks are going to be created in a hidden state
            {
                fltCurrentYCo = -50.0f;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                fltCurrentXCo = ((float)j*fltBlockOffSet) + fltLeftMost;    // Cast j into a float explicitly so that it doesn't it implicitly
                arrBlocks[i][j] = new Block(theGameEngine, fltCurrentXCo, fltCurrentYCo, fltCurrentZCo);
                if(fltCurrentYCo < 0)
                {
                    arrBlocks[i][j]->SetBlockState(Block::Destroyed);
                }   // End if
                else
                {
                    arrBlocks[i][j]->SetBlockState(Block::New);
                }
            }   // End of inner loop

            fltCurrentZCo += fltBlockOffSet;

        }   // End of outer loop

    }

    void CreateAGun()
    {
        // Create a gun
        Gun::Gun(theGameEngine);
    }

public:
    void Game::Run()
    {
        //Start watching input in a while loop
        // The main game loop, repeat until engine is stopped
        while (theGameEngine->IsRunning())
        {
            // Draw the scene
            theGameEngine->DrawScene();
            if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Escape))
            {
                theGameEngine->Stop();
            }

            if)theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
            {
                cout << "\n space";
            }

            GameStates currentGameState = enumGameState;
            switch(enumGameState)
            {
            case Ready:
                if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
                {
                    enumGameState = Firing;
                    cout << "\nGame State moved to Firing" << endl;
                }   // End if
                break;
            case Firing:
                if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
                {
                    enumGameState = Contact;
                    cout << "\nGame State moved to Contact" << endl;
                }   // End if
                break;
            case Contact:
                if (theGameEngine->KeyHit(Key_Space))
                {
                    enumGameState = Over;
                    cout << "\nGame State moved to Over" << endl;
                }   // End if
                break;
            case Over:
                break;
            };  // End of GameState switch
        }

    }
};  // End of Game Class
```

Comment: If you add std::endl to your prints to flush the line does that help? `std::cout << "Text" << std::endl;`

Comment: No, there is still nothing in the console output. I have tested the key_Space though, outside of the switch just now and it seems like the key press is not being read. Which is strange seen as the escape key capture works fine.

Comment: Sorry i realise thats not in the snippet above. Directly before the switch I have another theGameEngine->Key_Hit() for the escape key which quits the game. Working perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. The issue was not with the class, or code oustide of the class at all. It was an issue with visual studio, i'm not sure what unfortunately. When the code was copied out and added into a new project, it compiled perfectly, and all the break points placed in main were hit.

MORAL OF THE STORY: Try the obvious first.

Answer (score 4):

If your constructor has the following line of code, verbatim:

```
GameStates enumGameState = Ready;
```

Then what you've just done is create a *local* variable `enumGameState` within your constructor method and initialized it.  It goes out of scope as soon as the constructor is done, and its value is lost.

Presumably you also have a *member* variable `enumGameState` whose value is uninitialized, so your `switch` statement is run with bogus values.

Creating a local variable with the same name as a member variable is an example of *shadowing* in C++, and it often indicates an error.  For this reason, some compilers (like GCC) can display a warning if you shadow a variable; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958649/25507) for details.

Comment: The instance of GameStates is defined as enumGameState at the top of the class, only set to Ready inside the constructor.

Comment: @Stephen - Then I'm not sure what the problem is.  It's difficult to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Massive fail, added all the code by accident then tried to delete it out by editing the post and ended up with it in their twice. 

:( Sorry

PS. Please can a mod remove the excess code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define this enum in order to use it:

```
enum GameState
{
    Ready,
    Firing,
    Contact,
    Over
};
```

Then class `Game` could look like this:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game(GameState gs = Ready) : gs(gs) { }
    void update()
    {
        switch (gs)
        {
        case Ready: cout << "Ready\n"; gs = Firing; break;
        case Firing: cout << "Firing\n"; gs = Contact; break;
        case Contact: cout << "Contact\n"; gs = Over; break;
        case Over: cout << "Over\n"; break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
private:
    GameState gs;
};
```

And here's the `main`:

```
int main()
{
    Game g;
    g.update();
    g.update();
    g.update();
    g.update();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Ready
Firing
Contact
Over
```

Comment: I have a public enum GameStates defined, and an instance of it already. which i have named enumGameState, i assign this the ready value in the constructor which is also public. I am trying to use that same class variable here in the method.

Comment: Well, seems your implementation was correct. But it's good that you have decided to use enum instead of `int gameState;` ;)

Comment: I thought i was doing it correctly, but i have no idea why i don't get the desired outcome.

I really wish i hadn't left it until 24 hours before my hand in to restart my assignment now, though debugging the old one was much worse!

Comment: Check my example in this answer. Logic from your code remains same and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any issue with the class itself at all, I have found that when I run the Game main() is never entered, therefore the class never exists. It leaves me in another predicament all together, as that is where the game scene is drawn which appears to be rendered okay.

Thankyou for your time helping me debug the Game class code all the same.